# Vanishing of sections and special divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $L$ be a line bundle on a smooth complex projective curve $X$. Suppose we have vector subspaces $$U\subset V\subset H^0(X,L),\,\,\,\textrm{and}\,\,\,\dim\, U\leq k,\,\,\dim\,V=k+1.$$

I wonder if the following is true:

> Let $Q\in X$. Is it true that if there is a nonzero section $s\in U$,
>   vanishing at least $k+1$ times at $Q$, then there is a nonzero section in
>   $V$ vanishing at least $k+2$ times at $Q$?

Here is a clarification about my terminology:

1. I say that a section $v\in H^0(X,\mathcal L)$ "vanishes at least $p+1$ times at $Q$" if $(D^pv)(Q)=0$, where $D^pv$ is a section of the jet bundle $J^p\mathcal L$.
2. The condition that there exists an $s\in U$ vanishing at least $k+1$ times at $Q$ may be rephrased in a possibly more familiar way: the divisor $(k+1)Q$ is special of type $k+1$ for $(L,U)$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow all the hypotheses, but one can show at least by a standard sort of Riemann--Roch argument that this is true if $n$ is bigger than the genus of $X$.

Comment: I modified my question so that the hypotheses look now less intimidating. In practice I have a nonzero section $s\in U$ which vanishes "too many times", and I wonder if, knowing that there is a dimension jump between $U$ and $V$, I can conclude that in $V$ as well there is a section which vanishes too many times. ["too many times" $=$ more than the dimension of the vector space it lives in]